# Close connection to DB does not close all connections

Tags: java, sql, database-connection, datasource

I have connection leak to DB in my code.
The funny thing is that when I debug, all the connections are closed successfully (or when I do Thread.Sleep(100) ). but without that there is always one connection that stays!
Can you tell what is the problem here?

```
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = null;

        try {
            dataSource = dataSourceFactory.getDataSource(dbType, dbProps);


            dataSource.getConnection();

        } finally {
            if (dataSource != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    log.debug("validate() : Closing SQL connection pool");
                    DataSources.destroy(dataSource);
                    dataSource = null;
                    log.debug("validate() : SQL connection pool is closed");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.error("validate() : Error closing data source", e);
                }
            }       
        }
```

Comment: How do you check if a connection is still open? You seem to be using a connection pool, so if your database is still reporting open connection when your app closed them all, that might be correct (since the pool might keep some connections open in case you need another one in your app).

Comment: Thanks. I check if the connection still open with sql query in DB. 
Is it connected to the fact that the "open connection" is pretty closed to the "close connection"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017514/is-c3p0-thread-safe) regarding C3P0. I guess a `Thread.sleep(delay)` before `DataSources.destroy(dataSource)` solves your problem. I also guess that you know that some connection has been left intact checking your MySQL logs. However, apart from that in your case I would suggest to manually close the connection apart from the datasource which is something to do after every use of it. So I would suggest the following modification:

```
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        dataSource = dataSourceFactory.getDataSource(dbType, dbProps);
        // Get a connection from the datasource
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    } finally {
        if (connection!=null){
            connection.close();
        }
        if (dataSource != null) {
            try {
                log.debug("validate() : Closing SQL connection pool");
                DataSources.destroy(dataSource);
                dataSource = null;
                log.debug("validate() : SQL connection pool is closed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("validate() : Error closing data source", e);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved the problem - assign connection variable and release it explicitly.